# Jquery adds two <input> tags instead of only one

Tags: jquery

I'm having some difficulties with this code: in my website if I click on the $("#new-comment") button, jquery shows an input tag where I can write a comment, then I press enter and the new comment is added. But I have this problem: if I want to insert another comment immediately after the last insertion (without uploading the page, if I press f5 this doesn't happen), when I click on the button, jquery shows two input tags, each one appended after the other. If after having added a second comment, I want to write a third one, jquery shows three  tags and so on... I think that the problem is when I use the append function on the third line, but I don't know how to solve this.
(NOTE: I have written this line $newReview.remove(): because otherwise, after the enter pressing, jquery showed me another input tag with the same text I have written immediately after the new comment; this is also a problem).

```js
$("#new-comment").on('click',function(){ 
  var $newReview = $("<input class='new-input' type='text' id='insert' name='insert' placeholder='write here...'>");  
  $("#reviews").append($newReview);   
  $newReview.on('keypress',function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
      var comm = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url:'reviews/reviews_query.php',
        data: {put:true, title: $("#right_title").text(), script: comm.val()},     
        datatype:'json',
        success: function(json){
          var output = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
          var newName = "<span class='rev_name'>"+ output + "</span>";
          var newComment = "<span class='rev_comment'>"+ comm.val() + "</span>";
          $("#reviews > ul").html($("#reviews > ul").html()+"<li style='margin-bottom:20px'>" + newName + " " + newComment + "</li>");
        },
        error: function(e){
          console.log(e.message);
        }
      });
      $newReview.remove();
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: The point of Stack Snippets (the way you've put your code in the question) is to make them **runnable** by including the necessary HTML and libraries and such. Please update the snippet to include the minimum so that when we click **Run code snippet**, it runs and does what you've described.

Comment: I've tried with your suggestion, but the second time I want to add a comment, it doesn't show the input tag: I think that it is a problem only in jquery (as the execution doesn't exit the new-button click event)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the id of comment input after submitting.

Add

```
$newReview.attr('id', 'oldComment');
```

Before,

```
$newReview.remove()
```

Comment: Please let me know if this doesn't work, I will check for a new solution.

Comment: No, this was a good idea, but doesn't solve my problem (I have the same output as before)

Comment: Rep.ace $newReview.on('keypress',....   to.   $("newReview").on('keypress',....

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand why this solution should be correct (and it doesn't work, it doesn't let me press enter)